# Google Places API results not matching Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google Places API to find restaurants nearby to the given postcode. The lat/long that I am using in my API call are the same that are returned by Google Maps website, however the list of restaurants is almost 80% different.

My API call looks like below

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.4949254,-0.0138559&type=restaurant&key=API_KEY&radius=1000

What can I do to get more accurate results back from Google Places API, ideally the same list as returned from maps.google.com?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `keyword=restaurant` in place of `type=restaurant` in the query you will get results that are more similar to those returned by the Google Maps website.

Comment: Tried searching only by type, only by keyword and by both as well, however in all 3 cases I get different results and surprisingly none matches to the results I get from Google Maps website. I have also tried changing radius=1000 to rankBy=distance, still no luck. The lat/long that I am using are taken from the URL after I search my postcode on the website, so must be the same used by site.

Answer (score 0):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.4949254,-0.0138559&type=restaurant&key=[API_KEY]&radius=1000

Please check this above link is working for your, Please check your API Key

Comment: Hi, my API key is fine and I am getting the results back as well, however, as stated in my original post, the list of restaurants that I get through API call is different from the list of restaurants I see on maps.google.com for the same location.

Comment: By the way, I don't think sharing API keys publicly like this is a good idea. I suggest you should delete it from here and prevent any kind of mis-use.